# Codeception - HTML report generation seems slow?

Tags: unit-testing, acceptance-testing, codeception

I am using Codeception to run three acceptance tests which basically are as follows:-

- Check the email address 'admin@admin.com' exists
- Create a new user account
- Login to the website

Obviously this requires the database so I have added 'Db' to the list of modules in the acceptance.suite.yml, however the generation of the report takes sometime, is this normal or do I have something wrong with my setup?

Below is the report (and time taken for each according to the html file it is generating)

- check admin@admin.com account exists (AdminCept.php) (0.01s)
- create new user account (CreateUserCept.php) (19.1s)
- log in to the website (LoginCept.php) (21.72s)

Approx 40 seconds in total (although the command line states 1:02 - I guess as it replaces the mock database dump.sql back into the database as well)
Can anybody shed any light on the matter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really an answer but closing this off - simply put the report generation takes time.